# Symfony2 - Excluding current post on show page

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a show page and on the bottom the page I have a 'Related' articles section that show 4 related articles that the user can click on.

The problem is, I want to exclude the current article that is being shown from the 'Related' articles section on the bottom of the page so it doesn't appear twice.

Is there a conditional I can use in Twig to hide the current article I am showing in the 'Related' section so it doesn't appear twice (once for the show and again on the bottom of the page as a Related article) on the bottom of the page?

**Example of show page**

Show page - *Article 1*

blah...

...blah

blah...

**Related:** (4 articles on the bottom of page)

*Article 1*, Article 2, Article 3, Article 4 (I want to hide Article 1 in this section as it's being shown already)

**Related partial I am using:**

```
<h2>Related</h2>
<aside id="" class="">
    <div class='featuredfour cf'>
        {% for article in articles %}
            {% if not article.id == showedArticleId %}
            <div class="featuredfourpost">
                <a href="{{ path('acme_demo_article_show', { slug: article.slug }) }}">
                    <img width="150" height="150" src="{{ asset(['images/', article.image]|join) }}" class="" alt="" />
                    <h3 class="title">{{ article.title }}</h3>
                </a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</aside>
```

**Show page**

```
{% extends "AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% set showedArticleId = article.id %}

{% block body %}
[...]
<div class="entry-content">
    {% autoescape false %}
        <p>{{ include(template_from_string(article.body|raw|nl2br)) }}</p>
    {% endautoescape %}
</div>
[...]
{# Related Articles section #}
{{ include('AcmeDemoBundle:Partial:_featured.html.twig', { articles: articles }) }}

{% endblock %}
```

**Doctrine for relatedPosts**

```
public function getRelatedArticles($limit)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('article')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->orderBy('article.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

Comment: I think I would do that in `Twig`. Maybe I’d do two `Doctrine` queries: one for the shown article and one for the related articles which query 3 random articles except the one you’re showing.

Comment: I'm using 2 doctrine queries as you're suggesting, but not using 3 random except the one I'm showing. Can you elaborate on how to set this up in Doctrine?

Comment: Sure. Can you show us your actual Doctrine query?

Comment: You can use the simple `{% for article in articles if article != currentArticle %}..{% endfor %}`

Comment: Yeah, you can stick it in the include `{{ include('AcmeDemoBundle:Partial:_featured.html.twig', { articles: articles, currentArticle: article }, with_context = false) }}`.

Comment: @Qoop Worked. Awesome, definitely the simplest solution, thanks Qoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for your Doctrine query:

```
public function getRelatedArticles($exceptArticle, $limit)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('article')
        ->where('article != :exceptArticle')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->orderBy('article.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('exceptArticle', $exceptArticle);
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

You just give the article to except from the query.

Comment: Question, with this query I would have to hard code in the Id for `$expectArticleId` from the controller?

Comment: I edited my answer to give the article and not the article.id anymore.

Comment: How do I setup up `$exceptArticleId` to dynamically load from the article I select?

Comment: Ok but what do I put in the controller? `$articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Article')
            ->getRelatedArticles(..., 4);` for `...`?

Comment: First you get your shown article. I guess something like `$shownArticle = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Article') ->find($someId);` then you do `$relatedArticles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Article') ->getRelatedArticles($shownArticle, 4);`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your twig, on the part where you're showing the article, add (somewhere, without code is difficult to say exactly where)

```
[...]
{% set showedArticleId = article.id %}
[...]
```

Then use it for check and skip already showned one

```
[...]
{% for article in articles %}
  {% if article.id != showedArticleId %}
    [...]
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
[...]
```

Of course I'm making some guessing on your article entity fileds: I'm pretty sure that `id` will be there

Comment: Is there a specific place I add the `% set showedArticleId =...`? I added it inside the block body, just above the block body (see updated query) but now none of the Related articles are appearing.

Comment: I've dumped article.id in the show page and in the featured partial so the values are there, but for some reason it's not showing any of the Related articles.

Comment: @rollotomasi: could you update your code as I can see exactly what are you doing?

Comment: @rollotomasi: see my update, I've changed `not ... ==` in `!=`

Comment: The Related articles now appear but isn't excluding the one being shown.

Comment: Ok, I dumped showedArticleId from inside the if statement in the partial: and for some reason all Related posts are listed as int 11 --- which is the id of the article being shown.

Comment: When I dump article.id (in the partial if statement) the Ids are correct showing the different Ids for each Related post. `showArticleId` is showing 11 for each of them.

Comment: The article.id that's being shown is Id 11. But it's using the Id of 11 for the other Recent articles as well when I dump `showArticleId`.

Comment: Ok, I changed the `if not` to `if` and now it's excluding the post being shown. Thanks for your help and solution, sorry I didn't understand it at first. I've learned something new from Twig from you...thanks Don.